# Building a markup parser in php

Tags: php, parsing, markup

I have created a very simple markup parser in php. However, it currently uses str_replace to switch between markup and html. How can I make a "code" box of sorts (will eventually use GeSHI) that has the contents untouched?

Right now, the following markup: `[code][b]Some bold text[/b][/code]` winds up parsing as the code box with `<b>Some bold text</b>`.

I need some advice, which option is best?

- Have it check each word individually, and if it is not inside a [code] box it should parse
- Leave it as is, let users be unable to post markup inside of [code].
- Create another type of code box specifically for HTML markup, have [code] autorevert any < or > to [ and ].

Is there maybe even another option? This is a bit tougher than I thought it would be...

EDIT: Is it even worth adding a code box type thing to this parser? I mean, I see how it could be useful, but it is a rather large amount of effort for a small result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break it down into multiple strings for the purposes of using the str_replace.  Split the strings on the [code] and [/code] tags - saving the code box in a separate string.  Make note of where it went in the original string somehow.  Then use str_replace on the original string and do whatever parsing you like on the code box string.  Finally reinsert the parsed code boxes and display.

Just a word of warning though, turning input into html for display strikes me as inherently dangerous.  I'd recommend a large amount of input sanitization and checking before converting to html for redisplay.

Comment: It does not convert everything to html, only a specific array. And < and > are converted to their html entities ;)

Comment: And yeah, I am thinking that is what I will do.

Comment: That moment when you find an answer from 4 years ago.  And are horrified at your own suggestions o.O  Which is not to say that this method wouldn't work, but man is it far from the optimal solution.

Comment: Oh god I try not to look at stuff that old that I've written. And yeah, I've long since moved past methods like this

Answer (score 3):

Why would you reinvent the wheel?

There's plenty of [markup parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language) already.

Anyway, just str_replace won't help much. You'd have to learn regular expressions and as they say, [now you've got two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html) ;)

Comment: I like to try and build things myself if possible, plus I am nearly done anyway. Actually, str_replace works until we hit the code box speed bump.

Comment: In my time, I've reinvented the wheel numerous times, not because I'm pompous or do not like other people's code. It just makes you a better programmer and gives you the experience you need. I actually built a markup parser once (production quality) using regex. I can tell you that, this is not advisable. The security issues are a bit much. Though this is dated, for any future users, if you do build one, enjoy the learning experience, but I'd rather you don't use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

HTML beautifier is pretty sweet. http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier . The have a decorator class as well that would probably suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, your problem is in two parts. The first part is the need for a lexical analyzer to break your "code" into the keywords for your "language." Once you have a lexical analyzer, you then need a parser. A parser is code that accepts the keywords for your language one-at-a-time in a logical (usually recursive-descent way) manner.